# InstallShield Basic MSI: Targeting a particular Operating system

Tags: installshield, basic-msi

I am  a novice programmer and I just have started to learn InstallShield for a few days. I find something quite confusing that need support form experts:

In InstallScript, I can set the targeting platform/ operating system for the installation in Release wizard.

In basic MSI: I can only find the require operating system in the **Project Assistant** view.

That leads to my confusion:

1. Is targeting platform/ operating system and require operating system are the same thing? If not, does that means targeting operating systems are the only systems that my installation can run on; while require operating systems are the prerequisite, but not limited to, for my installation be able to run on?
2. Is there other ways that I could set the require operating system for my Basic MSI Installation rather than accessing the **Project Assistant** view?

There is so much I don't know, thus, your detailed explanations are much appreciated. Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check [Operating System properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370556(v=vs.85).aspx) and use those in conditions in the [LaunchCondition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369752(v=vs.85).aspx) table. The method of doing this is defined on [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc982261(v=vs.85).aspx).